# How do I change where the pointer is pointing to through a return statement?

Tags: c++

I have a Player object which holds an ID string. I'm trying to check if a player already exists by iterating through a list of Players. If the player already exists, I want to return the existing player, else I will make a new instance of the Player object.

```
Player *playerExists(const std::string &playerId, const std::vector<Player>* players)
{
    for (Player existingPlayer : *players)
    {
        if (existingPlayer.playerId == playerId)
        {
            std::cout << "Player " << existingPlayer.name << " exists" << std::endl;
            return &existingPlayer;
        }
    }
    return new Player();
}
```

The problem seems to be in the return statement. I don't know how to return the specific object to a pointer. This seems to be the only way I found not to get an error (talking about the & sing in the return statement).

```
Player* player = playerExists("SomeID", listOfPlayers);
listOfPlayers->push_back(*player);
delete player;
```

I'm quite new to using raw pointers so I probably just don't understand what the problem here is. I'd really appreciate if someone could explain what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Note that your `for` loop is making a copy of every `Player`, and returning an address of that is definitely wrong. Try looping with references to see if that solves the problem.

Comment: Note -- That entire code could have been a two-line function using `std::find_if` with no loops necessary.  As a by-product, that would have removed the mistakes in the `for` loop, since there would not be a `for` loop.

Comment: If allowed, replace `const std::vector<Player>* players` with `const std::vector<Player> & players`. The restrictions on a reference will give you somewhat safer code.

Comment: Yes, use `for (auto player = (*existingPlayer).begin(); player != (*existingPlayer).end(); player++)` use `player->playerId` and then return `player` if found. The elements of [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) are contiguous, so you can use an iterator (pointer) and return the pointer when found.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin your example is using iterators, not pointers. It would then be returning an iterator to the caller. Vector iterators are not guaranteed to be implemented as pointers.

Comment: Oops, correct, it should be `return &(*player);` The iterators do satisfy [LegacyRandomAccessIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator)

Comment: Do you want to add the new player to the list of existing players? Std::map< std::string,Player> might be a better container. Maybe also check out std::unique_ptr rather than use raw pointers. Also maybe set the Id of the new player within the function.

Comment: Your vector will be holding dangling pointers, meaning they point to invalid memory (as it has been freed/deleted), I would recommend using `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` as they automatically clean up the memory. (The second vector that you push into.)

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues with this code.

Each iteration of the loop is making a *local copy* of a `Player` in the vector, and thus will return a pointer to that *copy* if a match is found.  But when the current iteration is finished, that *copy* is destroyed, so you will end up returning a **dangling pointer**. To fix that, your loop need to take a *reference* to each `Player` in the vector:

`for (Player &existingPlayer : *players)`

The next issue is if no match is found, you return a `new`ed `Player`. The problem with that is the caller is then *unconditionally* `delete`ing the returned `Player*` regardless of whether it was `new`ed or not.  The vector owns the `Player` objects it is holding, so `delete`ing one of those objects is **undefined behavior**.

A better design choice is to have `playerExists()` return `nullptr` if no match is found. The caller can then do different things depending on whether a `Player` or a `nullptr` is returned, eg:

```cpp
Player* playerExists(const std::string &playerId, const std::vector<Player>* players)
{
    for (Player &existingPlayer : *players)
    {
        if (existingPlayer.playerId == playerId)
        {
            std::cout << "Player " << existingPlayer.name << " exists" << std::endl;
            return &existingPlayer;
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

```cpp
Player* player = playerExists("SomeID", listOfPlayers);
if (player) {
    // ID found, use player as needed...
    listOfPlayers->push_back(*player); // why re-add a player that is already in the list???
} else {
    // ID not found, do something else...
    listOfPlayers->push_back(Player{}); // why add a blank player???
}
```

Comment: Much simpler. You would need `const Player* playerExists(...)` and `for (const Player &existingPlayer : *players)` ( or just `auto`) for `const` correctness.

Answer (score 0):

Different ways of tackling this. Biggest problem might be in this line:

```
for (Player existingPlayer : *players)
```

It's making a copy (I think) of a player already in the collection.

When you do a `return &existingPlayer;` ... well it's returning an object on the stack. Bad things will happen.

You are better off iterating the collection and returning an iterator, IMHO... Maybe...

```
std::vector<Player>::const_iterator playerExists(const std::string &playerId, const std::vector<Player>& players)
{
    std::vector<Player>::const_iterator it = players.begin();
    for (; it != players.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (it->playerId == playerId)
        {
            std::cout << "Player " << it->name << " exists" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    return it;
}
```

You can always test after the return for

With the returned iterator, you'll have to do something with it...

```
auto it = playerExists(playerId, players);
if (it == players.end())
{
   // not found
} else {
   // found
}
```

Comment: The code won't compile, because `it` goes out of scope before the `return` is reached

Comment: @RemyLebeau Right you are. Moved iterator declaration out of loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is there :

```cpp
for (Player existingPlayer : *players)
```

In each iteration of the *for* loop, `existingPlayer` is a **copy** of the player that is stored in a local variable in the scope of the *for* loop. You are returning a pointer to a local variable which get destroyed after each loop iteration.

To avoid the copy, use a *reference* :

```cpp
for (Player &existingPlayer : *players)
```

Here, `existingPlayer` is a **reference** to the real player. This is what you did with the `const std::string` in the function prototype.

I have also some suggestions to possibly improve your code :

- **Avoid raw C pointers**, C++ give you tools to get the same functionnality in a (much) less error prone way and hence, more secure. If you don't need NULL as I see in your code, a reference is probably better. Else you should consider smart pointers ([`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr). I would pass `players` by reference instead of pointers in your case.
- `std::vector` may not be the best container. **Choosing the right container can be difficult.** Currently you are iterating over the whole array to find the player by his id. You should use a `std::unordered_map<std::string,Player>` that use a hash table and probably speed up lookup time. **I would also use a typedef** of `std::a_container_class<Player>` to avoid massive code rewrite if you change the container kind or write one from scratch later.
- **Does copying a `Player` make sense ?** If not, explicitly delete [copy constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) and [copy assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment), the compiler will then throw an error if you want to copy the `Player`. **Note that this is a design choice** that I often do, multiple instance of the same player is normal depending on your objects design.
- I'm doubtful about `return new Player();`. Why do you return a new player if no player exist ? With my personal interpretation (might be totally wrong), I would return an iterator. No pointer involved, you can "dereference" the iterator to get a reference to the found player and the non existence of player is signaled by return an iterator equal to `players.end()`. But beware a big drawback, be sure to test before modifying the container and invalidating iterators.

**With my own design choices**, I made a slightly untested and shorter version of your function :

```cpp
#include <unordered_map>
typedef std::unordered_map<std::string,Player> PlayerCollection;
/* ... */
PlayerCollection::const_iterator playerExists(const std::string &playerId, const PlayerCollection &players)
{
    return players.find(playerId);
}
```

Keep in mind that my suggestions are opinionated and are not the absolute truth. **Read the other answers which have different ideas.**